# Can't get appengine:devserver_stop to work on Windows 2012 server

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, maven, appengine-maven-plugin

On my Windows 2012 server, I can run "mvn appengine:devserver_start" without any problems. When I run "mvn appengine:devserver_stop", it says "Stopping the development server" then "BUILD SUCCESS" but the process remains running and I have to kill it manually. Can't seem to find much information on these two goals (they're still pretty new) so wondering if this is a known issue or if it's something on my server.

I've tried both from TeamCity and running from the command line directly (with and without admin privileges).

Comment: Just confirmed that it doesn't work on Windows 7 (64-bit) either

Comment: I'm having the same issues on OSX. I found a way to patch the code, but I'm wondering how I can get my patch accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can stop it using command line prompt.
get the PID using command

C:\netstat -a -n -o
and stop the process by another command

C:\Taskkill /PID <2004> /F

Full description with output is [here](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.in/2014/05/appenginedevserverstop-not-working-in.html).

Comment: We ended up using wmic instead: wmic process WHERE "CommandLine like '%%appengine%%' and CommandLine like '%%-p 8888%'" call terminate